# Change background color on click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an element with ID `test`. If i click on it, i want the `background-color` to be changed to red. I tried it like this, but it does not work.

```js
var main = function()
{
  $("#test").click
  {
      function()
      {
          $(this).css("background-color","red");
      }
  };
}
$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div id="test">!!!</div>
  <div>C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: after click you need to have `(` and need to close it with `)` not with `{` and `}`

Comment: omg, im such a beginner, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").click(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","red");
    });
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div id="test">!!!</div>
  <div>C</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have error in your code. Incorrect syntax while defining click event via jquery. it should be:

```
var main = function(){
$("#test").click(function()
  {           //^---- { should be (
      $(this).css("background-color","red");
  });
}
$(document).ready(main);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your call syntax is wrong. You should use the click like `click(function(){})`. .

```
var main = function(){
    $("#test").click(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","red");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply css as an object. So you can define your object in your javascript like this:

```
var my_css_class = { backgroundColor : 'blue', color : '#fff' };
```

And then simply apply it to all the elements you want:

```
$("#myelement").css(my_css_class);
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for this tipp, i did not know!